# Access public final static field from tml page

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a grid where I would like to load the data from method. This method is taking String as a parameter and produce necessary List as output.
For example, it can look like this:

```
public List<SomeObject> getContactBasedOnType(final String type)
    {
        final List<SomeObject> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        ...//based on "type" list will be populated by different data
        return returnList;
    }
```

and then in my tml page I will use it as follows:

```
<t:grid t:source="getSomeData('STRING')"...
>...</t:grid>
```

Now, I would like to replace 'STRING' with a public static String field from a class other than component class, for example:

```
<t:grid t:source="getSomeData(com.example.Class.STATIC_FINAL_FIELD)"...
>...</t:grid>
```

Is there any way I can do that directly? So without using any additional methods in a component class or annotated fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve what you asked, but it's an **awful hack**.

```
<t:grid
t:source="getSomeData(getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass('com.example.Class').getField('STATIC_FINAL_FIELD').get(getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass('com.example.Class').getField('STATIC_FINAL_FIELD').getType().newInstance()))">
...
</t:grid>
```

*Note that, in your question, the method in the component class is named `getContactBasedOnType` while in your tmls you are referencing `getSomeData`. The method names must match, of course.*

Again, the above is a terrible hack, but the only solution I got to work under the constraint that the component class may not be touched.

Making the list a property of the component class and populating it in the setupRender() method would be a much better design.